# How to execute plain Celery tasks on Airflow workers

Tags: python, flask, celery, airflow

I currently have Airflow set up and working correctly using the CeleryExecutor as a backend to provide horizontal scaling. This works remarkably well especially when having the worker nodes sit in an autoscaling group on EC2.

In addition to Airflow, I use plain Celery to handle simple asynchronous tasks (that don't need a whole pipeline) coming from Flask/Python. Until now, these plain Celery tasks were very low volume and I just ran the plain Celery worker on the same machine as Flask. There is now a requirement to run a massive number of plain Celery tasks in the system, so I need to scale my plain Celery as well.

One way to do this would be to run the plain Celery worker service on the Airflow worker servers as well (to benefit from the autoscaling etc.) but this doesn't seem to be an elegant solution since it creates two different "types" of Celery worker on the same machine. My question is whether there is some combination of configuration settings I can pass to my plain Celery app that will cause @celery.task decorated functions to be executed directly on my Airflow worker cluster as a plain Celery task, completely bypassing the Airflow middleware.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The application is `airflow.executors.celery_executor.app` if I remember well. Try `celery -A airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect active` for an example in your current Airflow infrastructure to test it. However, I suggest you do not do this because your Celery tasks may affect the execution of Airflow DAGs, and it may affect the SLAs.

What we do in the company I work for is exactly what you suggested - we maintain a large Celery cluster, and we sometimes offload execution of some Airflow tasks to our Celery cluster, depending on the use-case. This is particularly handy when a task in our Airflow DAG actually triggers tens of thousands of small jobs. Our Celery cluster runs 8 million tasks on a busy day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on how Celery tasks may affect the Airflow DAGs if done the first way? Is it because they add extra load to the servers, or because they pass through the Airflow infrastructure perhaps? Also, when you say you guys do what I suggested, do you mean you run both flavours of Celery worker on a node, or do you have different types of node for each?

Comment: Because you may take all the available worker processes. And those important ones would wait and may miss the SLA.